# ASP.net ParseControl if else statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, parsecontrol

Hope someone help me with this.

Is this possible in asp.net?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control parsed = this.ParseControl(@"<% if (true){ %> <div> Show True 
                                       Content </div> <%} %>");          
    myPlaceholder.Controls.Add(parsed);    
}


<asp:View id ="myPlaceholder" runat="server" />
```

EDIT:
and I also try this still doesn't work and others

```
<asp:PlaceHolder id ="myPlaceholder" runat="server" />
```

If this is possible how can I achieve this?.

Comment: can you please explain what you want to do?

Comment: I would like to parse if else statement inside of <asp:PlaceHolder if it was possible because parsing html statement like this 
<asp:Label ID="user_name" runat="server" /> is working.

Comment: I don't THINK that it is possible. But can't you just do that at code? For example: string test; if (true) test = @"<div>Show true content</div>" else test = @"<div>Show false content</div>" Control parsed = this.ParseControl(test);  myPlaceholder.Controls.Add(parsed);

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, Thanks for your time to help me. I'm just planning to make Dynamic template Tags in ASP.net 2.0.